# Can I set a default search with the PicNet Table Filter?

Tags: jquery, filter, default

I've created a table that's using the PicNet Table Filter, and I would like to add a default search to one of the fields; the column is "Hrs Ago", and I want the default to be "<30".  Is this possible?  Google and the docs got me nowhere.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry there is no support for default values baked in to the table filter as yet.  However you could use jQuery to do this for you.  Simply:

```
$('#filter_1').val('<30').trigger('keyup')
```

Tnx

Guido

Comment: I am using picNet filter along with tablesorter pager plugin. Is there a way to make the PicNet filter work across all pages?

Comment: Hi Gatapia, I'm having the same issue and this didn't work for me. Do you have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#filter_1').val('<30').trigger('keyup')
```

does not seem to work for me.

Instead of it I've found a method that does work:

```
$('#filter_1').val('<30')
    .parents('table:first')
        .tableFilterRefresh()
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to use

```
$('#filter_1').val('<30').keyup(); //For textfield filters
$('#filter_1').val('Option_1').change(); //For dropdown select filters
```

Comment: Hi Matt, I tried your suggestion but could get it to work. Do you have any other suggestions?